# im new to coding itself so i want to know how to fix this

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

```
x = 10

print(x)
```

the message i get:

```
PS H:\VS Code\100 Days of Code\Day16 - OOP> conda activate base
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.       

At line:1 char:1

+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

 
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32


Warning:

not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation


 
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'X' is not defined


>>> print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Good for you! trying to learn a bit of coding... It seems you DO have python installed, but I'm not sure if it has something to do with you calling it from a virtual environment. Please do a little research on the link provided in the warning and update your question, posting how you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic error, showing that `conda` is not installed, or at the very least that it is not accessible by the command-line where you are attempting to run this. Its unrelated to Python.

I'm not sure why you are using `conda` for this task, but I assume it is related to this `100 Days of Code` thing?

Does the program give you some instructions on how to set up your environment? Maybe try going over that again.

You may also find some benefit in using a dedicated python editor, which would allow you to work on your python files without running through Powershell.

If you are positive that Powershell + Conda is correct, you will need to install Conda, and expose it to the powershell path.

Comment: i got it to work now, it seems that i try runnning the codde by using shift+enter which cause it to not working, but after i run it in terminal with the run button it seems to work now